# JAVA regex struggle

Tags: java, regex

I have Sample Text like these lines:

```
onmouseover="show(someText, some 1234, 'word')" height="60" onClick="do(1)">&nbsp;
onmouseover="show(someText, some 1234, 'word')">&nbsp;
```

I'm using `java.util.regex`.. My regex looks like this (unescaped):

```
(?<=over\=\"show\()(.*)(?=\)\")
```

I want to match only the characters between the braces but for the first line in sample text it matches everything until the last brace:

```
someText, some 1234, 'word')" height="60" onClick="do(1
```

I have read something about lazyness and possessive quantifiers and tried several approaches but I could'nt get it to work.

How do I have to design the suffix?

Comment: java or javascript struggle?

Comment: i'm using java.

Comment: Its not a duplicate of the link in above comment cause I'm asking for JAVA regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the [solution](https://regexr.com/3hqtn)

```
(?<=over\=\"show\()(.*?)(?=\)\")
```

you have to put a `?` behind your `.*` to make it fetch lazy (not eager)

Comment: Amazingly fast answer. Thank You. I tried it with `?` but in the suffix group.